# Keras. How to change model for it not to use Embedding layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

There is a BLSTM RNN that is currectly trained with an embedding layer. I want to change it to train purely on the input sequences. I am somehow not completely sure where to start making changes.

Does anyone have sugestions?

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word2int) + 1,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=True)
sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)

l_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))(embedded_sequences)
preds = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags + 1, activation='softmax'))(l_lstm)
```

Comment: Are you currently using Keras Tokenizer to prepare the input data?

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting *change it to train purely on the input sequences* two ways:

- Either you want your LSTM to actually run on integers `[34, 21, 8, ...]` directly in which case you need to say that every timestep there is only 1 integer, i.e. convert `(batch_size, max_seq_len)` to `(batch_size, max_seq_len, 1)` which can be achieved using `embedded_seqs = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, -1))(sequence_input)`. This will force the model to see actual integer values but I wouldn't recommend it.
- Another option would be one hot encode it so there is no trainable embedding but a large vector for each word with a 1 at the corresponding index. You can do this by removing `weights=[embedding_matrix]` and adding `embeddings_initializer='eye'` to your `Embedding` layer setting `trainable=False`.